# Is it possible to use wildcards in SVN Authz file?

Tags: svn, authorization

Here's my tree structure:

```
project/tag/v1.0 
project/tag/v2.0 
project/tag/v3.0 
... 
project/tag/v10.0
```

Inside each of the tag is a folder named *secret folder*. What I would like to do is give everyone read access to the above, while restricting access to *secret folder*.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible starting with version 1.10.x. See https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10.html#authzperf

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried to include the following into my authz file:

[:glob:/project/tag/*/secretfolder]

However, I got an invalid authz configuration response. If my path above is correct, then I'm guessing we are on a pre-1.10 version. Gotta have a chat with IT on Monday to confirm.

Comment: Confirmed we are on 1.8.14. Now just need to convince management to upgrade, not that they care they're 5 years out of date. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[:glob:repo:/basePath/**/trunk]
@lead = rw
@readonly = r
```

Where,
:glob: - syntax to specify that there are wild cards in the repo path
:repo: - name of repo
** - Wild card present in the path

Update your .authz file to have something like this and it will work.